# How do I select & cycle through only listboxes in VB (ignoring all other controls)?

Tags: vb6, listbox, controls

My form has a bunch of controls like command buttons and listboxes.  I created a "left" and "right" button to cycle through the controls, but then I realized that I really only want to cycle through **listboxes**, ignoring all other controls that are not listboxes.  Here's my code, but I realize now that it cycles through ALL controls, both command buttons, text boxes, AND listboxes.  How do I make it so that it ignores all controls EXCEPT listboxes.  Essentially, I am making these L and R buttons cycle through only listboxes, kind of like using Tab and Ctrl+Tab to cycle back and forth.

```
Private Sub FocusListBoxByTabIndex(offset As Long)
Dim ctrl As VB.Control

For Each ctrl In Me
    If TypeOf ctrl Is ListBox Then
        If ctrl.TabIndex = lastFocus.TabIndex + offset Then
            ctrl.SetFocus
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
Next
End Sub

Private Sub Command2_Click()  'left button
    FocusListBoxByTabIndex -1
End Sub

Private Sub Command3_Click()   'right button
    FocusListBoxByTabIndex 1
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works, but only if you remember what control has current focus.
So if you also use mouse or tab to cycle controls you need each control to use the _GotFocus event and then set CurTabIndex.

```
Private CurTabIndex As Integer

Private Sub Form_Load()
    CurTabIndex = 0
End Sub

Private Sub FocusListBoxByTabIndex(offset As Long)
    Dim ctrl As VB.Control
    Dim FirstControl As VB.Control

    For Each ctrl In Me
        If TypeOf ctrl Is ListBox Then
            If offset > 0 Then
                If ctrl.TabIndex >= CurTabIndex + offset Then
                    If FirstControl Is Nothing Then
                        Set FirstControl = ctrl
                    ElseIf FirstControl.TabIndex > ctrl.TabIndex Then
                        Set FirstControl = ctrl
                    End If
                End If
            Else
                If ctrl.TabIndex <= CurTabIndex + offset Then
                    If FirstControl Is Nothing Then
                        Set FirstControl = ctrl
                    ElseIf FirstControl.TabIndex < ctrl.TabIndex Then
                        Set FirstControl = ctrl
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next

    If Not FirstControl Is Nothing Then
        CurTabIndex = FirstControl.TabIndex
        FirstControl.SetFocus
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Command2_Click()  'left button
    FocusListBoxByTabIndex -1
End Sub

Private Sub Command3_Click()   'right button
    FocusListBoxByTabIndex 1
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in VB6. If this is due to a performance hit (MANY controls on form), there are ways to make it more efficient. You could create an array/collection of listbox controls and cycle through that array/collection.

Answer (score 0):

can't you create your listboxes as a control array

```
listbox(offset).setfocus
```